# Program seems to skip inner for loop

Tags: c++, loops, breakpoints

I use VS2017 studio community.
I want to back-substitute a matrix that is already forward-eliminated. So I made the corresponding template function.

```
template<typename element_type>
inline void backwardSubstitution(std::vector<std::vector<element_type>> & mat,
std::vector<element_type>&sol) {
    sol.resize(mat.size());
    unsigned int col_size = mat[0].size();

    double numerator ;
    double multiplier;
    for (unsigned int col_id = col_size - 1; col_id > -1; --col_id) {

        //INNER LOOP!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        for (unsigned int row_id = mat.size(); (row_id < col_id + 1) && row_id > -1; --row_id) {

            if (row_id == col_id) {
                numerator = mat[row_id][col_id];
                mat[row_id][col_id] = 1.;   
                mat[row_id][col_size] /= numerator;
            }
            else
            {
                multiplier = -mat[row_id][col_id];
                mat[row_id][col_id] = 0.;
                mat[row_id][col_size] += multiplier;
            }

            sol[row_id] = mat[row_id][col_size];
        }
    }
    return;
}//Point to which VS2017 jumps
```

And I tested it with a matrix.

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> small_mat3 = {
    { 144.0000, 12.0000, 1.0000, 9.0000 },
    { 0       ,  2.9167, 0.8264, 5.4375 },
    { 0       ,       0,-0.2000,-0.9714 },
};
std::vector<double> sol;
backwardSubstitution(small_mat3, sol);
std::cout << std::endl;
print(small_mat3);//print function I defined.
for (double element : sol) {
    std::cout << element << std::endl;
}
```

The result is as follows:

1) small_mat3: Same as before.

```
144 12 1 9
0 2.9167 0.8264 5.4375
0 0 -0.2 -0.9714
```

2) sol: Same as initialized in backSubstitution().

```
0
0
0
```

Nothing happened. So, I marked the line of the function as a break point and started debugging. And when the step passes by the first loop, that is, when it meets the INNER LOOP, my VS2017 just goes to point right after return command.
I have made a similar mistake once and then I was told that the condition always was not fulfilled. But the current problem I faces with seems not to be such a thing like that.

Comment: "`col_id > -1;`" -- `col_id` is an `unsigned` integer. Can you explain how an unsigned integer could possibly be ever less than -1? What exactly do you expect to accomplish by comparing an unsigned value with -1? Once you figure out the answer to this question, and study what your C++ book says about converting negative values to unsigned types, you should be able to figure out why your program doesn't work.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I want to make the for loop work only when col_id is larger than or equal to 0.

Comment: `unsigned int row_id = mat.size();` Probably should be `unsigned int row_id = mat.size() - 1;`

Comment: An unsigned value will always be larger than or equal to 0. No matter what you do with it. According to the laws of physics of our shared universe, an unsigned value is always greater or equal to 0, by definition. Do you understand that? And do you know what happens when a negative value is compared to an unsigned value? Here's a hint. Try this: `unsigned int v=-1; std::cout << v << std::endl;`. See what output you'll get here.

Comment: Instead of counting down from size-1 to 0, count up from 0 to size-1. Then subtract the counter from size-1 to get the index.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank you. I solved the problem and extra errors I found after I solved the problem you commented.

Comment: Stop adding crap to your question title. If you want to post an answer, do that.

Comment: @melpomene Okay